# How do I associate my ICacheClient with a separate database in ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, servicestack

We are using ServiceStack with an `OrmLiteCacheClient`.  We are using PostgreSQL and two different schemas within one database.  I created custom interfaces for both connections (one for each schema in the db), and they both inherit from `IDbConnectionFactory`.  How do I make certain that my cache is using the connection I want it to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, they both use the same `IDbConnectionFactory` that's registered in your IOC.

Comment: Couldn't you use the IoC to register an instance of the `OrmLiteCacheClient` where the `DbFactory` has been manually set to a second instance of  `IDbConnectionFactory` in the AppHost?  Then ICacheClient will resolve to the registered instance on one DB connection, and all other DB connections will use the base DB registration.

Comment: @jklemmack There can only a singleton instance of IDbConnectionFactory registered, supporting multiple db connections requires [registering named connections](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#multi-nested-database-connections) or implementing a [custom MultiTenant DbFactory](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/MultiTennantAppHostTests.cs#L53) to be able to change what connection is used at runtime. OrmLiteCacheClient doesn't include support for non-default DbConnections.

Answer (score 1):

I did something very similar to this in a recent website.  I have a main OLTP database which shares data & processing with back-end systems, and a second database just to support Caching & front-end related information.  The main thing is that the second DB can NOT be used to auto-wire into services, not without some additional jiggery-pokery.

Here's what I put in my AppHost `Configure`:

```
    IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString,
            SqlServerDialect.Provider
            );

    // Register the main database as the default singleton
    container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(dbFactory);
        IDbConnectionFactory dbCacheFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(

    // Create a second factory, but ONLY use it to instantiate the Cache
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BottleDropCache"].ConnectionString,
            SqlServerDialect.Provider
            );
    var cache = new OrmLiteCacheClient();
    cache.DbFactory = dbCacheFactory;
    cache.InitSchema();
    container.Register<ICacheClient>(cache);
```